# How can I rearrange the items in a list into groups of 4 so that no item in a group has been in a group with the other items in that group before?

Tags: python, unique, combinations, probability

So my girlfriend was asked to group the girls in her sorority into groups of 4. She needs to do this for 4 different events (1 event per week). There are 168 girls total (convenient that it fits into groups of 4 evenly). The caveat is that no girl can be in a group with a girl that they've already been in a group with before.

When she told me this problem I told her I could code her a little script that would do this, no problem. I didn't think it would be this challenging...

Initially I thought I would write a little script in python that would use a random number generator to randomly select girls from the list of girls and place them into groups of 4. Each group would have an incrementing ID starting with 1, and NOT resetting for new events (so the first group for event 2 would have an ID of 43). Each girl would would be an object that on top of her name, would also contain the IDs of the groups that she's been in already. For future iterations/events, I would again randomly select girls from the list and put them into groups of 4, but would have checks to make sure that there are no overlaps in their previous group IDs. If a girl fails the check, re-seed the number generator and keep generating a random number until it matches the index of a girl who passes the check.

I still think this would work (unless this problem is mathematically impossible), but it would be SOOOOO slow and inefficient. I know there must be a more elegant solution than brute-forcing combinations of groups.

How could I accomplish this task?

Answer (score 1):

Imagine four rings placed one above other in 42(number of groups that can be created with 168 girls with 4 girl in each group) consecutively standing poles. Each part of those ring bisecting with the pole is one girl. Each time you want to make a group of girls that have not been in same group. Just rotate every ring one plus time. I dont know If you could visualise what I tried to imply or not or may be I might not have been able to express myself properly. Your problem was interesting so I wrote a python function to try to express it in code. I did not test it to be honest but I hope this should work. Here is the code.

```
def group_girls(girls, what_time=0):
    # Create four groups containing girls
    rings = {}
    for i in range(0, 4):
        rings[i] = []
    for girl_number in range(len(girls)):
        rings[girl_number % 4].append(girls[girl_number])
    # Create a group now
    groups = {}
    for group_number in range(42):
        groups[group_number] = []
        apparent_index = group_number
        for j in range(4):
            apparent_index += what_time
            groups[group_number].append(rings[j][apparent_index])
    return groups
```

'what_time' is number of event you want to select girls for.
I hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

With only 4 total events, you can use a simple algorithm. Arrange all the girls arbitrarily into a matrix with 4 columns and 42 rows. Each row is a group for the first event. Then, shift column 2 down one row, shift column 3 down 2 rows, and shift column 4 down by 3 rows. You now have a new grouping for the 2nd event. Repeat two more times to get the groupings for the 3rd and 4th events. Since each column is shifted by a different amount, and no column is ever shifted by the full 42 rows, no two girls will ever share the same row twice.

(Obviously this strategy will not generate the maximum number of valid groupings, but it will certainly give you 4 of them.)

Answer (score 0):

I tested it, it works. brute algorithm.
42 groups for each events. a girl always has different group mates in all events.

```
import itertools, random

def gen_groups(items, c):
    t = items[:]
    random.shuffle(t)
    size = len(t) / c
    for i in xrange(c):
        yield tuple(sorted(t[i*size:(i+1)*size]))

def has_collision(plan0, plan1):
    for g0 in plan0:
        for g1 in plan1:
            if len(set(g0) & set(g1)) > 1:
                return True

def main():
    items = range(168)
    events = set()
    for e in xrange(4):
        while True:
            groups = tuple([g for g in gen_groups(items, 42)])
            collision = False
            for pre_groups in events:
                if has_collision(pre_groups, groups):
                    collision = True
                    break
            if not collision:
                events.add(groups)
                print '-- event %s --' % (e + 1)
                print groups
                break
    print 'done'

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try a type of "musical chairs" (i.e. [circular shifts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circular_shift)) among people at tables/groups.

**Code**

```
import collections as ct

import more_itertools as mit


def shift(iterable):
    """Return a list redistributed subsets."""
    # Prepare empty containers
    tables = [()] * len(iterable)

    assignments = ct.deque(tables)
    for k, sublst in enumerate(zip(*iterable)):
        # distrib list to each position
        for i, item in enumerate(sublst):
            assignments[i] += (item,)
        assignments.rotate(-(k+1))
    return list(assignments)

size = 2*2
lst = list(mit.windowed(range(1, 169), n=size, step=size))


# Arrangement for the first four weeks
week_0 = lst
week_1 = shift(lst)
week_2 = shift(shift(lst))
week_3 = shift(shift(shift(lst)))
```

**Demo**

```
>>> week_3
[(121, 110, 87, 52),
 (125, 114, 91, 56),
 (129, 118, 95, 60),
 (133, 122, 99, 64),
 (137, 126, 103, 68),
 (141, 130, 107, 72),
 ...]
```

Note: we use the third-party `more_itertools.windowed` to quickly build subsets of four groups.

---

**Details**

Consider a smaller population of 16 numbered people seated at tables of four.  For some *m* rotations, you can ensure no collision of one member with any other member in the population, given the following:

> For each rotation, every member is moved *`i`* tables away from its last table placement.

For example, in the following diagram take the first table of the *A* rotation.  In the next rotation, *B*:

- The person seated at index 0 moves 0 tables away from the last placement.
- The person seated at index 1 moves 1 table away from the last placement.
- The person seated at index 2 moves 2 tables away from the last placement.
- ...

In short, this procedure simply redistributes people across all available tables.

[image]

Notice that beyond the half-way point, collisions start to occur (as seen in red and orange positions for rotations *C* and *D*).  In fact, the original arrangement can be achieved if rotated sufficiently (*E*).  While this algorithm is sensitive to the size of the population, collisions are increasingly more rare for larger populations with fewer rotations.  Therefore, your requirements of 168 for four weeks (rotations) will work fine without risk of guests meeting each other again.  Now if they happen to be friends, that is an altogether separate challenge.

See sample code for the latter illustration here:

```
lst = list(mit.windowed(range(1, 17), n=size, step=size))

a = lst
b = shift(lst)
c = shift(shift(lst))
d = shift(shift(shift(lst)))
e = shift(shift(shift(shift(lst))))
```